# Mysql database is not starting in Bitnami wamp stack

Tags: mysql, service, innodb, wampserver, bitnami

My mysql database in the bitnami wamp stack stopped unexpectedly and I am not able to restart it again. When I try to start the mysql from wmap stack manager it is continously showing 'starting' for hours. There is no change in the status. I have tried to start the mysql service from windows services, then I am getting a service timeout error.Following is the log I am getting in my mysql logs :

[image: Following is the log I am getting in my mysql logs]

Comment: it is difficult to guess with but i think you need to clean up the previous startup.

Comment: how can i do that?